Synchronizing event handler on Dispose

Note: while this question contain details from Selenium WebDriver with Chrome DevTools, I believe that the question is relevant in a more general context of thread synchronization too.

I have code that captures all network requests from the browser and does something with them (logging is a classical example, but sometimes I do other, more sophisticated things with it). For that I created an event handler for the Network.RequestPaused event. When the handler completes doing whatever it needs to do, it calls Network.ContinueRequestWithoutModification to continue sending the request from the browser. In my real usage I sometimes also call Network.ContinueRequestWithResponse, modify the request and more, but in the example below I only call Network.ContinueRequestWithoutModification for simplicity.
Note that the Network.RequestPaused event is triggered on a different thread than the one on which the test runs.
Everything seems to work fine, but occasionally I receive the following exception in the call to Network.ContinueRequestWithoutModification from the event handler:
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException : The WebSocket is in an invalid state ('CloseSent') for this operation. Valid states are: 'Open, CloseReceived'
When I investigated this issue I realized that I get this exception around the same time that I Dispose the DevToolsSession object (which also owns the Network object). It makes sense that the exception would occur because the handler is executed on a different thread, and it’s possible that I call Network.ContinueRequestWithoutModification during, or even a bit after, DevToolsSession.Dispose is executed. I managed to reproduce the problem with the following test (though only with [Repeat(20)])
    [Test, Repeat(20)]
    public void EventHandlersCanRunAfterDevToolsIsDisposed()
    {
        using var driver = new ChromeDriver();
        var caughtExceptions = new List<Exception>();

        using (var devToolsSession = driver.GetDevToolsSession(new DevToolsOptions { ProtocolVersion = 127 }))
        {
            var networkAdapter = new NetworkAdapter(devToolsSession);
            var fetch = new FetchAdapter(devToolsSession);
            var network = new V127Network(networkAdapter, fetch);

            var enableCommandSettings = new EnableCommandSettings
            {
                Patterns = new RequestPattern[]
                {
                    new()
                    {
                        RequestStage = RequestStage.Request,
                        UrlPattern = "*"
                    }
                }
            };
            fetch.Enable(enableCommandSettings);

            network.RequestPaused += async (_, args) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // Do some stuff...
                    await network.ContinueRequestWithoutModification(args.RequestData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    caughtExceptions.Add(ex);
                }
            };

            driver.Url = "https://www.google.com";
        } // Disposing DevToolsSession

        if (caughtExceptions.Count != 0)
            throw new AggregateException(caughtExceptions);
    }


Note: even if I unregister the event handler before disposing DevToolsSession I still might get the exception, as the handler may already have started.

How can I avoid these exceptions? I tried to think about all kinds of thread synchronization mechanisms, but I didn’t find any simple and robust solution.

You have another bug in that caughtExceptions is accessed from multiple threads without any synchronization.

You're right. I should replace it with ConcurrentQueue

Improved the original solution based on Servy's comments and also refactored the counter logic into its own type to make the use simpler.
class OperationCounter {
    int count = 0;
    const int stopValue = -1;

    public OperationRegistration? Register() {
        int initial, incremented;
        do {
            initial = Volatile.Read(ref count);
            if (initial == stopValue) {
                return null;
            }

            incremented = initial + 1;
        }
        while (initial != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref count,
            incremented, initial));

        return new OperationRegistration(this);
    }

    public struct OperationRegistration : IDisposable {
        OperationCounter _operationCounter;

        public OperationRegistration(OperationCounter countHolder) {
            _operationCounter = countHolder;
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _operationCounter.count);
        }
    }

    public void Finish() {
        while (0 != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref count, stopValue, 0)) {
            Console.WriteLine("operations in progress");
            Thread.Sleep(100); // or spin
        }
    }

    // Non-blocking version for avoiding possible dead-locks
    // if SynchronizaitonContext forces everything on the same thread
    public async Task FinishAsync() {
        while (0 != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref count, stopValue, 0)) {
            Console.WriteLine("operations in progress");
            await Task.Delay(200);
        }
    }
}

public class Network {
    public event EventHandler RequestPaused;

    public void FireEvent() {
        RequestPaused.Invoke(null, null);
    }

}

public class Session : IDisposable {
    public void Dispose() {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing");
    }
}

and the use:
var session = new Session();
var network = new Network();

var operationCounter = new OperationCounter();
network.RequestPaused += async (sender, args) => {

    // using the using statement for finally
    // so we can decrement the registration counter there
    using var operationRegistration = operationCounter.Register();
    // if we couldn't get a registration then we have disposed/finished
    if (operationRegistration is null) {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing called");
        return;
    }
    await Task.Delay(1);
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

};

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var captured = i;

    Task.Run(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(captured * 250);
        network.FireEvent();
    });
}

Thread.Sleep(500);

// wait til we dont have active operations
// before we can dispose
operationCounter.Finish();

session.Dispose();


This doesn't fix the race condition.  The dispose call can run when any number of event handlers are past the read and before the increment, after which point all of those event handlers will be using the disposed resource.

Also exceptions result in count being off, resulting in the code getting stuck.

@Servy thanks for the corrections. Does the edited version address those?

Rather than trying to write your own locking primitives, just use the existing tried and tested .NET locking mechanisms.  Even if you write something that I personally can't find any bugs in, you'll have way less confidence that the code is in fact valid.

@Servy thanks for looking at the edited answer. Didn't think of any locking mechanism that fits well given OP's requirements. Looking forward to reading alternative answers.

You can just use lock.  That should be your default means of synchronizing access to things.

@Servy - lock on what?
I also tried to implement something similar but found that it still has race conditions. The question is what can I do?

I would register to disconnected event of the websocket and validate the state of it before running the event, implementing this operation protection is too complicated

@ElishevaWasserman that sounds as a good approach, but first I don't own the websocket connection directly, it's managed by Selenium. And second, I don't see that ClientWebSocket exposes any event.

I believe I found a solution. I ran it for with [Repeat(500)] and it passed, so I believe it's fine.
The main idea is to use a CountdownEvent object to track the number of active handlers, and to wait for them to reach zero. The counter is initialized to 1 and not to 0, to indicate that we still didn't get to Dispose yet. Before we reach Dispose we signal (decrement) the CountdownEvent, and inside the handler we call TryAddCount() and check its result. If it's 0, it means that no handlers are currently running and that we reached Dispose, so we exit. Otherwise this call increments the counter and we continue to complete the event handler. In the handler's finally we call Signal() to decrement the counter back. The last thing we do before Dispose is calling Wait() to ensure that no all handlers have exited.
Here's the full code:
    [Test, Repeat(1000)]
    public void EventHandlersCanRunAfterDevToolsIsDisposed()
    {
        var executingHandlers = new CountdownEvent(1);

        using var driver = new ChromeDriver();
        var caughtExceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();

        using (var devToolsSession = driver.GetDevToolsSession(new DevToolsOptions { ProtocolVersion = 127 }))
        {
            var networkAdapter = new NetworkAdapter(devToolsSession);
            var fetch = new FetchAdapter(devToolsSession);
            var network = new V127Network(networkAdapter, fetch);

            var enableCommandSettings = new EnableCommandSettings
            {
                Patterns = new RequestPattern[]
                {
                    new()
                    {
                        RequestStage = RequestStage.Request,
                        UrlPattern = "*"
                    }
                }
            };
            fetch.Enable(enableCommandSettings);

            network.RequestPaused += async (_, args) =>
            {
                if (!executingHandlers.TryAddCount())
                    return;

                try
                {
                    // Do some stuff...
                    await network.ContinueRequestWithoutModification(args.RequestData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    caughtExceptions.Enqueue(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    executingHandlers.Signal();
                }
            };

            driver.Url = "https://www.google.com";

            executingHandlers.Signal();
            executingHandlers.Wait();

        } // Disposing DevToolsSession

        if (!caughtExceptions.IsEmpty)
            throw new AggregateException(caughtExceptions);
    }


Actually I still occasionally get an exception System.IO.IOException : Cannot access a closed stream. from DevToolsSession.Dispose. This looks more like a bug in Selenium to me (because I don't close the stream in the event handler), but I can't be sure :(

I believe I found a solution. > since the logic of the solution is exactly like my answer which you've commented on (hence have read), I think it is customary stackoverflow practice to acknowledge it...Using the built-in CountDownEvent is indeed probably better.

With all the respect @IvanPetrov , I don't think that your solution is similar to mine whatsoever.

yeah, it's so dissimilar that I just replaced three lines of code from yours to mine and it worked the same...

Looking at it again I see the similarity in the high-level scheme and its usage, but the implementation is very different, and in threading issues this is critical. Btw, I don't know who downvoted to your answer, but it wasn't me, and I wouldn't do it. I also don't know who downvoted my answer, but that's also not relevant.

Also, for the sake of truth, I got my idea from Chat GPT which was much closer to my final answer than yours, though it had some issues that I fixed by myself.

@IvanPetrov In what way are they even slightly related?  You tried to build a new synchronization tool from scratch using lock free programming and busyloops, while this uses a .NET synchronization tool specifically designed to solve that problem.  There's nothing about them that's even similar beyond that they're attempting to answer the same question.

@ArnonAxelrod what's the difference? It's a counter that we increment/decrement in the same way.

@Servy I don't recall you mentioning the obvious use of CountdownEvent when I genuinely asked you yesterday of how you'd use built-in types. I've used CountdownEvent in other circumstances and didn't think of it. You being one of the most highly rated person here in those topics could have said that instead of mentioning lock as a comment to my inquiry.

@IvanPetrov Odd that you accuse me of not telling you something that you think is obvious.  And you also seem to think that using a lock wouldn't be entirely appropriate for solving this problem too.  But that's not what the question I asked you was.  Since it seems you forgot, the question was "In what way are they even slightly related?"  You're accusing this person of plagiarizing your answer, and yet there's almost nothing even similar about them beyond what's inherent to the underlying problem.

@Servy 1. My original solution relied on maintaining a counter for maintaininig a count in a thread-safe(attempt at) way. You commented on two cases I hadn't considered, so you are familiar with it. 2. After I took your comments into account and revised the solution by incorporating the counters into its own type which in hindsight is a poorman's CoundDownEvent. 3. You acknowledged that you don't find any apparent weaknesses but it should be relied on other primitives / built-in types. 4. You most likely can read the code of CountDownEvent in source so you know that mine is...

... a watered down version of it. 5. OP uses CountDownEvent at the same places in the code I did to increase/decrease the counter. It's not as apparent because I changed the names of methods, but a person at your level should recognize this. 6. Acknowledging that there are alternative ways by using lock you acknoweledge that the way things are solved by both me and OP are not inherent to the problem and they are alternative approaches.


I was offended at the fact that OP while commenting on my code either didn't actually test it which is quite disrespectful given that it was the only answer which you said that had no apparent weaknesses in your second comment.  Or he got the idea for the counter and as it turned out with the help of ChatGPT came to another solution based on the "counter" idea and not the lock



You had no business commenting under this answer as OP already ACKNOWLEDGED that the solutions are SIMILAR upon investigating mine (which he should have done BEFORE posting the answer OR after my initial comment which he outright disregarded


@IvanPetrov "You acknowledged that you don't find any apparent weaknesses" Care to quote me on that.  I said no such thing. (6) Basically the only similarity between your code and this answer is that something somewhere contains a conceptual numeric value to represent the number of ongoing handlers.  That's the extent of their similarity.  And that similarity is inherent to the nature of the problem and would still exist were you to use a lock, as I would personally do.

@Servy " Even if you write something that I personally can't find any bugs in, you'll have way less confidence that the code is in fact valid." here you go ...

@Servy should I screenshot the comment before u delete it?

@IvanPetrov In general, if anyone posts an answer in which they attempt to badly re-implement a synchronization primitive in .NET, and there are comments pointing out obvious flaws with it, it's entirely reasonable for any reader to just use the .NET implementation and not even attempt to test someone else's re-implementation (until and unless the .NET implementation is shown to be problematic).  It's what I would do myself.

@Servy so you are deflecting? And obviously you could just said "That's just watered-down and auntested version of CountDownEvent why don't you use that.."

@IvanPetrov I have just as much right to comment as anyone.  If I see someone accusing someone of plagiarism where none exists, I can, and will, comment with my viewpoint on the matter.  You're free to ignore it if you want.  I can't force you to read it.

@IvanPetrov You quoted me telling you that I didn't even evaluate it further, and that I wasn't going to continue testing  your code for you because the fundamental strategy was so inherently flawed.  I pointed out a bug in the first draft because it was so immediately obvious at a glance, because I wanted to be considerate.

@Servy so "something that I personally can't find any bugs in" this means I have not read it in Servy-talk. Good to know.

@IvanPetrov Considering how many times you've insulted me, argued in bad faith, and attacked me personally, should it really be a surprise that I haven't done more than I already have to help you fix your answers?  The gall to demand I do even more given how you've treated me.  Yes, I could have told you all of the numerous existing tools you could have used instead.  I figured you could manage to find one of them on your own.  The OP beat you to it.  And now you're mad at us both.

@Servy I haven't insulted you AT ALL. Now this is prime fascea bad-faith and strawman. I thanks you for your comments, incorporated them in a revised version of the answer and quoted you. I am not asking you NOW to further evaluate my answer as you imply.

@IvanPetrov When I've reviewed something, feel that is is a quality solution that doesn't have bugs, I say that.  I don't tell people that, if I were to review it and find no bugs, which is phrased as a hypothetical, to refer to something that I've actually done.  I was telling you that your solution is so flawed it wasn't worth reviewing.  That you interpreted it as being bug free is on you.

@Servy I am not mad, I was actually happy because this validated my approach. Especially when I looked at the source code of CountDownEvent.

@Servy you didn't phrase it - "if I were to review it"...

You asked me to review it, I told you it wouldn't be trustworthy regardless of what I said because of high-level problems you hadn't addressed.  If I had reviewed it and felt it was a good implementation I'd have said that.  I told you my review of it wouldn't matter.  Given that I feel my review of it wouldn't matter why would I review it in depth.

"I told you it wouldn't be trustworthy regardless of what I said because of high-level problems you hadn't addressed." No, you told me "Rather than trying to write your own locking primitives, just use the existing tried and tested .NET locking mechanisms. " I did address the issues you mentioned in my edited version that I asked you to review which encapsulated the logic in its own type (similar to what MS introduced with CountDownEvent in .NET Framework 4.0)
